# Trace Width, Length, and Clearance for SATA signals in KiCad PCB Design

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, signal-integrity, high-speed, sata

I am looking to design a SATA adapter board which interfaces an FPGA LPC FMC connector with a SATA connector. This board will contain the 6 signals (RX+, RX-, TX+, TX-, and Clk+, Clk-) along with series capacitors for each signal as shown below

- Clock: The clock signal is a 150 MHz LVDS signal at 1.2V and is generated from an onboard oscillator. This signal is created on-board and is fed into the FMC connector.
- SATA TX: This signal is generated by the FPGA using the input clock, and is an output from the FMC connector to the SATA connector, which interfaces with the SATA device. This signal operates at SATA 1/2 speeds (1.5/3 gigabit per sec).
- SATA RX: This signal is generated by the SATA device and is an input into the FPGA through the FMC connector and SATA connector. It operates at the same speed as the TX line.

I have found a similar [open-source example](https://github.com/antmicro/fmc-sata-adapter) of one such board which I have reproduced below. Here, the four top-most signals are the TX/RX lines, while the lower two lines are the input clock. It should be noted that this design uses a higher pin count FMC connector, and also interfaces an M.2 key rather than a SATA cable connector.

[image: SATA PCB layout]

For this implementation, I have the following questions:

1. How can the trace width and length for these signals be calculated and set in KiCad? Is the distance between traces relevant for signals at this speed? And if so, how can this be set in KiCad?
2. The TX/RX lines contain 10nF series capacitors while the clock line contains a 100nF series capacitor. Where should these capacitors be placed and what is their relevance in this design (i.e. should the values change for Gen1 vs Gen2)?
3. What is the relevance of the trace length vs trace skew options in KiCad for these signals? I understand that each of the signals must be routed as differential pairs, but would like to understand when to emphasize the length of the trace vs skew of the signal.
4. At these speeds, what other considerations must I take into account when designing this board (internal layer usage, copper weight, board material, inductance, dielectric)?

Comment: The spacing and width of the traces is absolutely critical. Read up on controlled impedance before attempt to route GHz frequency signals.

Comment: I think you need more distance between successive wiggles in your length extension snake pattern.